# Android OpenCV Error: Assertion failed

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm developing an android image processing application using Opencv.
in this App I take each frame of camera and process it to find hand.
I searched a lot and did some things but I couldn't solve the problem:

1- I resized the input image to reduce the size cause I'm working on mobile.

2- I made a small application with an small image as input and exactly use this method to find convex hull but again this error occurred .

the error is :

```
 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || len == ((vector<uchar>*)v)-  >size() / esz) in virtual void cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int const*, int,    int, bool, int) const, file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-  SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1489
```

exactly in below line of the makeContours() method:

```
convexHull(Mat(hg->contours[hg->cIdx]),( (vector<Point>)hg->hullP[hg-  >cIdx]), false, true);
```

And the makeContours() mehtod where I make convexhull and convexdefects is this:

```
void makeContours(MyImage *m, HandGesture* hg){
    Mat aBw;

    pyrUp(m->bw, m->bw);
    m->bw.copyTo(aBw);
    findContours(aBw, hg->contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    hg->initVectors();
    hg->cIdx = findBiggestContour(hg->contours);

      if (hg->cIdx != -1){




    hg->bRect = boundingRect(Mat(hg->contours[hg->cIdx]));

    convexHull(Mat(hg->contours[hg->cIdx]),( (vector<Point>)hg->hullP[hg-  >cIdx]), false, true);

    convexHull(Mat(hg->contours[hg->cIdx]),((vector<int>) hg->hullI[hg->cIdx]), false, false);

    if (((vector<Point>)hg->contours[hg->cIdx]).size()>3){
        convexityDefects(((vector<Point>)hg->contours[hg->cIdx]), ((vector<int>)hg->hullI[hg->cIdx]),((vector<Vec4i>) hg->defects[hg->cIdx]));

        hg->eleminateDefects(m);
    }
    bool isHand = hg->detectIfHand();
    hg->printGestureInfo(m->src);
    if (isHand){
        hg->getFingerTips(m);
        hg->drawFingerTips(m);
        myDrawContours(m, hg);
    }
}
}
```

Any help greatly appreciate.

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33694170/5008845) (bottom part) helps.

Comment: thanks   @Miki   here again I disabled the error for invalid arguments,and write it like this :                                       convexHull(Mat(hg->contours[hg->cIdx]),hg->hullP[hg->cIdx], false, true);
  convexHull(Mat(hg->contours[hg->cIdx]),hg->hullI[hg->cIdx], false, false);                                                                                                   and It works!

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed that also this post is yours.. :D