# Invalid arguments in ConvexHull Android ndk and Opencv

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I have this C++ OpenCV code in my jni folder of android application `hello-jni.cpp`. I just want to find and draw convexhull but cause of `hull[i]` the convexhull method generate an error "*invalid arguments*". If I cast `(vector<point>(hull[i]))` the program runs and generates this error:

> libc "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1)"

Any help really really appreciated.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "hellojni"
#define  LOGI(...)    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define ORIGCOL2ANDROIDORGCOL CV_BGR2BGRA

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {

    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL      Java_com_elmira_getconvexhull_MainActivity_convertNativeGray(
        JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrGray);
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL     Java_com_elmira_getconvexhull_MainActivity_convertNativeGray(
        JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrGray) {

        Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
        Mat& mGray = *(Mat*)addrGray;

        int conv = 0;
        jint retVal;

        Mat src; Mat src_gray;
        src = mRgb;

        cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));

        Mat src_copy = src.clone();
        Mat threshold_output;
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<vector<Point> > hull(contours.size());
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        int thresh = 100;

        threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY || CV_THRESH_OTSU);

        /// Find contours
        findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));


        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "inmethod", "size %d *** %d", contours.size(), threshold_output.cols);

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false, false);
        }
        retVal = (jint)conv;
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize  `hull`

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<vector<Point> > hull(contours.size());
```

`hull` size is `0`, since `contours` size is 0. So when you access `hull[i]` you are accessing out of bounds.

Declare `hull` after `findContours`:

```
 findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
 vector<vector<Point> > hull(contours.size());
```

---

You can also simply call `convexHull` as:

```
 convexHull(contours[i], hull[i]);
```

since 3rd argument `orientation` is false by default, and 4th argument `returnPoints` is ignored when 2nd argument is a `std::vector`.

---

`thresh` value is ignored when you use `THRESH_OTSU`.

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that there are some problems with Android NDK. A simple workaround is:

- disable the error for invalid arguments, or
- use the following

Code:

```
Mat mHull;
convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), mHull, false, true);
hull[i].assign(mHull.begin<Point>(), mHull.end<Point>());
```

Comment: thanks for your response.I did what you said but now the program runs and generate this error:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || len == ((vector<uchar>*)v)->size() / esz) in virtual void cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int const*, int, int, bool, int) const, file /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1489

Comment: exactly in this line convexHull( Mat(contours[i]),(vector<Point>(hull[i])));

Comment: Change that line to: `convexHull(contours[i], hull[i]);`

Comment: totally I have problem with using vector of vectors in c++ ndk in android any where I use vector of vectors or vectors of custom objects I have to cast them I did a lot of things to solve this problem but I couldn't.
cause of that I cant write this convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false, false) and I have to cast hull[i].don't you think the assertion error is for this cast?

Comment: when I write  convexHull(contours[i], hull[i]); this error appear "Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void convexHull(const cv::_InputArray &, const cv::_OutputArray &, bool, bool)
'"

Comment: @elnaz.bfrhn See updated answer. This workaround should work as expected. Please let me know

Comment: voila! the problem solved    @Miki   ! I did what you said and then disable the error for invalid arguments and the problem solved ! great .. thanks a billion!